# How to debug application in extjs in internet explorer and Google chrome browser

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

Can anybody tell How to debug application in  extjs in internet explorer  and google chrome Browser? is it possible using Breakpoints to debug to check the values?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific... Is there something in particular that isn't working in your app? Or some area of the app that you are having trouble with? As @cclerville points out in his answer, Chrome has very good Developer Tools, IE is getting better (in 9+ anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article provided by sencha. check the section for internet explorer, http://www.sencha.com/learn/debugging-ext-js-applications

Answer (score 0):

I have been forced to use IE8 in an application which works in Chrome and Firefox but fails often in IE8.

Debugging ExtJS in IE8 is nearly impossible if the problem is in the framework. IE8's developer tools hangs loading ext-all-dev.js

Also you can't get stack trace as in Chrome.

I had to put alert() calls in suspect lines and the whole process is a nightmare.

If you can avoid IE, do it.

Else be VERY VERY patient...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Developer Tools for your browsers. I don't use IE but I use Chrome's Developer Tools all the time! And yes you can do breakpoints, check values, etc..